# Bootstrap fix div element on top and prevent resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to fix a div element on the top by scrolling. 
I have achieved this with the following code:

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;
if (!msie6) {
    var top = $('#betslip').offset().top - parseFloat($('#betslip').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= top) {
        // if so, ad the fixed class
        $('#betslip').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        // otherwise remove it
        $('#betslip').removeClass('fixed');
    }
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
#betslip.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="betslip">
...
</div>
```

The problem is that, while scrolling the div element is getting larger. How I can fix/prevent this?

Here is a screenshot after and before the scrolling:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By adding `position: fixed;` to `#betslip` it will ignore width of container. Try adding `width: inherit;` to `#betslip`.fixed

Comment: i have added the width: inherit, and now the div is not so bright as before, but it is still not with the original size. i have tried to add additional to the fixed class also some col md-6 class, but no effect :(

Comment: it's hard for me to understand what happening in there without html+css code provided.